# How do I run the yolov4 model in a web application?

Tags: web-applications, object-detection, tensorflow.js, yolo

I want to implement my yolov4 model to run with a web application. I found several tutorials to do that, among them are [Kosta Malsev](https://medium.com/swlh/build-custom-object-detection-web-application-using-tensorflow-js-d1664f96a18b) and [Sascha Dittman](https://github.com/SaschaDittmann/tfjs-cv-objectdetection) . However, [Kosta Malsev](https://medium.com/swlh/build-custom-object-detection-web-application-using-tensorflow-js-d1664f96a18b) uses a webcam as input, whereas I want to use upload images as input. I ended up following [Kosta Malsev](https://medium.com/swlh/build-custom-object-detection-web-application-using-tensorflow-js-d1664f96a18b) only to the point of converting my model into the Tensorflowjs model. Then to create the web application, I followed [Sascha Dittman](https://github.com/SaschaDittmann/tfjs-cv-objectdetection), but when I tried to run the github, the model never loaded successfully. When I tried to replace his model with mine, the model loaded successfully. But when I try to make predictions, the predictions never finish, and when I open the web console it says error [image: Activation leackyrelu has not been implemented for the WebGL backend]

Then when I tried to follow [Kosta Malsev](https://medium.com/swlh/build-custom-object-detection-web-application-using-tensorflow-js-d1664f96a18b) to adjust tensorflowjs version when converting model with version in html file `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>`, I got the error:

[image: Shapes can util_base.js:357 not be < 0. Found -2 at dim 2].

Can you guys help me? Thank you. Here is the codes of index.html and predict.js file.

```js
let imageLoaded = false;
$("#image-selector").change(function () {
    imageLoaded = false;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        let dataURL = reader.result;
        $("#selectedImage").attr("src", dataURL);
        removeHighlights();
        imageLoaded = true;
    }
    
    let file = $("#image-selector").prop('files')[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

function showProgress(percentage) {
    var pct = Math.floor(percentage*100.0);
    $('.progress-bar').html(`Loading Model (${pct}%)`);
    console.log(`${pct}% loaded`);
}

let model;
let is_new_od_model;
let modelLoaded = false;
$( document ).ready(async function () {
    modelLoaded = false;
    $('.progress-bar').html("Loading Model");
    $('.progress-bar').show();
    console.log( "Loading model..." );
    model = await tf.loadGraphModel('model/model.json', {onProgress: showProgress});
    is_new_od_model = model.inputs.length == 3;
    console.log( "Model loaded." );
    $('.progress-bar').hide();
    modelLoaded = true;
});

function _logistic(x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x)));
    } else {
        const e = Math.exp(x);
        return e / (1 + e);
    }
}

async function loadImage(onProgress) {
    console.log( "Pre-processing image..." );
    await $('.progress-bar').html("Pre-processing image").promise();
    
    const pixels = $('#selectedImage').get(0);
        
    // Pre-process the image
    const input_size = model.inputs[0].shape[1];
    let image = tf.browser.fromPixels(pixels, 3);
    image = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image.expandDims().toFloat(), [input_size, input_size]);
    if (is_new_od_model) {
        console.log( "Object Detection Model V2 detected." );
        image = is_new_od_model ? image : image.reverse(-1); // RGB->BGR for old models
    }

    return image;
}

const ANCHORS = [0.573, 0.677, 1.87, 2.06, 3.34, 5.47, 7.88, 3.53, 9.77, 9.17];
const NEW_OD_OUTPUT_TENSORS = ['detected_boxes', 'detected_scores', 'detected_classes'];
async function predictLogos(inputs) {
    console.log( "Running predictions..." );
    await $('.progress-bar').html("Running predictions").promise();
    const outputs = await model.executeAsync(inputs, is_new_od_model ? NEW_OD_OUTPUT_TENSORS : null);
    const arrays = !Array.isArray(outputs) ? outputs.array() : Promise.all(outputs.map(t => t.array()));
    let predictions = await arrays;

    // Post processing for old models.
    if (predictions.length != 3) {
        console.log( "Post processing..." );
        await $('.progress-bar').html("Post-processing V1 model").promise();
        const num_anchor = ANCHORS.length / 2;
        const channels = predictions[0][0][0].length;
        const height = predictions[0].length;
        const width = predictions[0][0].length;

        const num_class = channels / num_anchor - 5;

        let boxes = [];
        let scores = [];
        let classes = [];

        for (var grid_y = 0; grid_y < height; grid_y++) {
            for (var grid_x = 0; grid_x < width; grid_x++) {
                let offset = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < num_anchor; i++) {
                    let x = (_logistic(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x][offset++]) + grid_x) / width;
                    let y = (_logistic(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x][offset++]) + grid_y) / height;
                    let w = Math.exp(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x][offset++]) * ANCHORS[i * 2] / width;
                    let h = Math.exp(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x][offset++]) * ANCHORS[i * 2 + 1] / height;

                    let objectness = tf.scalar(_logistic(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x][offset++]));
                    let class_probabilities = tf.tensor1d(predictions[0][grid_y][grid_x].slice(offset, offset + num_class)).softmax();
                    offset += num_class;

                    class_probabilities = class_probabilities.mul(objectness);
                    let max_index = class_probabilities.argMax();
                    boxes.push([x - w / 2, y - h / 2, x + w / 2, y + h / 2]);
                    scores.push(class_probabilities.max().dataSync()[0]);
                    classes.push(max_index.dataSync()[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        boxes = tf.tensor2d(boxes);
        scores = tf.tensor1d(scores);
        classes = tf.tensor1d(classes);

        const selected_indices = await tf.image.nonMaxSuppressionAsync(boxes, scores, 10);
        predictions = [await boxes.gather(selected_indices).array(), await scores.gather(selected_indices).array(), await classes.gather(selected_indices).array()];
    }

    return predictions;
}

var children = [];
function removeHighlights() {
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        imageOverlay.removeChild(children[i]);
    }
    children = [];
}
async function highlightResults(predictions) {
    console.log( "Highlighting results..." );
    await $('.progress-bar').html("Highlighting results").promise();

    removeHighlights();
    
    for (let n = 0; n < predictions[0].length; n++) {
        // Check scores
        if (predictions[1][n] > 0.66) {
            const p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerText = TARGET_CLASSES[predictions[2][n]]  + ': ' 
                + Math.round(parseFloat(predictions[1][n]) * 100) 
                + '%';
            
            bboxLeft = (predictions[0][n][0] * selectedImage.width) + 10;
            bboxTop = (predictions[0][n][1] * selectedImage.height) - 10;
            bboxWidth = (predictions[0][n][2] * selectedImage.width) - bboxLeft + 20;
            bboxHeight = (predictions[0][n][3] * selectedImage.height) - bboxTop + 10;
            
            p.style = 'margin-left: ' + bboxLeft + 'px; margin-top: '
                + (bboxTop - 10) + 'px; width: ' 
                + bboxWidth + 'px; top: 0; left: 0;';
            const highlighter = document.createElement('div');
            highlighter.setAttribute('class', 'highlighter');
            highlighter.style = 'left: ' + bboxLeft + 'px; top: '
                + bboxTop + 'px; width: ' 
                + bboxWidth + 'px; height: '
                + bboxHeight + 'px;';
            imageOverlay.appendChild(highlighter);
            imageOverlay.appendChild(p);
            children.push(highlighter);
            children.push(p);
        }
    }
}

$("#predict-button").click(async function () {
    if (!modelLoaded) { alert("The model must be loaded first"); return; }
    if (!imageLoaded) { alert("Please select an image first"); return; }
    $('.progress-bar').html("Starting prediction");
    $('.progress-bar').show();

    const image = await loadImage();
    const predictions = await predictLogos(image);
    await highlightResults(predictions);

    $('.progress-bar').hide();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>TensorFlow.js: Azure Logo Detector</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Use the power of Machine Learning to detect Azure Logos.">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <style>
            body {
                min-height: 75rem;
                padding-top: 4.5rem;
            }

            .bd-placeholder-img {
                font-size: 1.125rem;
                text-anchor: middle;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            @media (min-width: 768px) {
                .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                    font-size: 3.5rem;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Azure Logo Detector</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <main role="main" class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated mb-2">Loading Model</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input id="image-selector" class="form-control border-0" type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button id="predict-button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Predict</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="ml-3">Image</h2>
                    <div id="imageOverlay" class="imageOverlay">
                        <img id="selectedImage" class="ml-3" width="500" alt=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="target_classes.js"></script>
        <script src="predict.js"></script > 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include the code for it.

Comment: @yudhiesh I think I already attach the github that I used. But, ya I already insert the index.html and predict.js too now.